# mail from ssms using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am able to get email notification using the below code:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Send Mail',
@recipients = 'xyz',
@subject = 'Email notification',
@query= 'select count(*) from Employee;'
```

The result is a number.

I want to see the result as: `Total employee = xx`

Am getting error with the following statement

```
@query= ' "Total Employee = " select count(*) from Employee;'
```

> Error: Incorrect syntax

Please suggest the correct way to write the `@Query` part to get the result in desired format.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@query` parameter should be something like this:

```
@query= 'select ''Total Employee = '' + CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(10)) from Employee;'
```

Comment: Did you get an error? Can you say why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Give something like this a shot:

```
Declare @count nvarchar(10) = (select count(*) from Employee)

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Send Mail',
@recipients = 'xyz',
@subject = 'Email notification',
@body= 'Total Employees - ' + @count
```

Comment: None of this will work. You are assigning a string into an `int` variable on the first line -> `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select count(*) from Employee;' to data type int.`

Comment: @R. Richards Does it work when you change it to nvarchar(10)?  I don't have sql mail to test it with.

Comment: No, not at all. All this is doing is sending the select statement in the body of the email; the select will never get executed like this. `nvarchar(10)` isn't even long enough to hold the whole select statement you have in your answer. Are you just guessing at this point?

Comment: @R. Richards One more try

Comment: Third times a charm, I guess.

Comment: @R. Richards Didn't know that c&p answers were a requirement on SOE, I do however advise you to read every line of a post before responding, namely the 1st line of mine.